# Double spring validation

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I have a trouble with a hibernate + spring validation. During execution of my ajax post-request the @InitBinder annotated method calls 2 times. In result I got double errors in the BindingResult object. I use this dependencies:

```
<spring-security.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<validation.api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation.api.version>
<hibernate.validator.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${version.spring}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>${validation.api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My controller class:

```
@Autowired
private MailConfigValidator mailConfigValidator;

@InitBinder("config")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(mailConfigValidator);
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateConfig", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public NamedEntity updateConfig(@RequestBody @Valid Config config, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new NamedEntity(0L, getMessage("config.valid.failed"));
    }
    configService.saveConfig(config);
    return new NamedEntity(1L, getMessage("config.update.success"));
}
```

Config class also have an annotated field in its parent class:

```
@NotBlank
private String name;
```

I have placed '**sysout**' in the constructor of controller class and it have bean called just 1 time, so spring-context rises just once. Can someone say what is wrong?

Comment: Init binder is used for request params as well as for the model attributes. If you have ones the it could be called for them. You can check the target object by calling: `binder.getObjectName()`

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I my case, I have only "config" in console both times.